# Mysql query logic not getting the same results

Tags: mysql, logic

I have a few queries to determine how many IPs came back this month. It doesn't count as 'coming back' if the IP came back on the same day. It only counts if the IP comes back on another day. So here are my queries, but there's something wrong with either my logic or the queries:

```
SELECT COUNT( ip ) 
FROM ipAll 
WHERE YEAR( DATE ) = '2015' 
AND MONTH( DATE ) = '12'
```

**All IP:**  875

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT ip ) 
FROM ipAll 
WHERE YEAR( DATE ) = '2015' 
AND MONTH( DATE ) = '12'
```

**Distinct IP:**  588

**IP That Came Back This Month:**  875-588=287;

```
SELECT ip, COUNT( ip ) AS matches 
FROM ipAll 
WHERE YEAR( DATE ) = '2015' 
AND MONTH( DATE ) = '12' 
GROUP BY ip 
HAVING matches >1 
ORDER BY matches DESC
```

**Rows that returned:**  104

So, I'm kind of confused. The first result, said that there are 287 IP that came back this month, but the second result said that there are 104 IP that came back this month. What am I doing wrong, or what logic am I confusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second query gives you distinct ip's.

The third query tells you that you have 104 ip's that appear 2 *or more* times.

there's no contradiction here, you probably have many ip's returning more than twice. the result of second and third should not necessarily add up to the first one.

Comment: So the IP That Came Back This Month is 104, and NOT 287? Because, I minus 875-588=287;

Comment: @jessica - yes. 104 came back more than once. 287 is the total times that those who came more than once came

Answer (score 0):

> IP That Came Back This Month: 875-588=287;

With this, you are supposing that each IP only come back once. What if it's only one IP coming back 287 times ?
The last query tells you indeed that it's only 104 IPs coming back (the sum of their returns will give you 287).
So I think that your logic's wrong :)